# React newbie: sharing state across unlinked components

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-redux, react-on-rails

I'm a React newbie trying to integrate React into a Rails site. I have a `CommentForm` component at the very top of the page/html, and a `Comments` component at the bottom of the same page. At present, both are rendered through React-On-Rails' `react_component` method.

The problem is that, upon submitting a form in `CommentForm`, I'd like to change `this.state.comments` in the `Comments` component. I'm familiar with the idea of ensuring state is bubbled up to a common parent component, but at present, these two components don't have a common parent (or any parents at all).

So, with the disclaimer that I've been learning React for all of 2 days and am likely very confused, what's best practice for overcoming this sort of issue? Options as I see them:

- Rewrite the entire rails view as a single parent component with the two components as children underneath. This doesn't sound fun - there's a lot of html generated by a lot of rails helpers between the two components on the page
- Use Redux to create a store that's shared between the two components(???)
- Somehow create a parent component while still rendering the two other components in separate parts of the page(?)
- Accessing `Comment`'s state attributes from within `CommentForm` or  some shared resource (eg: `window` scope), which, from my limited understanding, isn't the React Way

I'm guessing this is a common problem, but I'm uncertain what the general wisdom is to fix it. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first option would be doing *the react way only* (with no external libraries). If your project it's not that big, could be a solution.

The third and fourth option are definitely not the way to go.

For what you said, using Redux seems to be the *easiest* solution.

The `Comments` component should be drawing all the comments in your global store and the `CommentForm` should add the comments to the store (and probably send an AJAX request for saving server side also).

Then, these components will share the same `Provider` and have access to same Store.

I'd suggest you watching [Dan's Course](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux)

Comment: I took a night to work through Redux, and it's clearly the right solution. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Redux is the perfect use case for this honestly. It doesn't take too long to implement but if you've never done it before you're gonna need a day or two to wrap your head around it.

In general, as your project grows even more, you will have a much easier time managing one state instead of a thousand component wide states.

So, if you're gonna have more situations like this, or situations where you have to pass down props through more than 3 components. I'd implement Redux now and be future proof.